# How to set cookie on external domain using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, phantomjs

Hello I want to ask if is it possible to set cookie on external domain using PhantomJS? I tried below code..

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36';


phantom.addCookie({
  'name'     : 'ps_idssss',   /* required property */
  'value'    : '123123',  /* required property */
  'domain'   : 'casperjs.org',
  'path'     : '/',                /* required property */
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60)   /* <-- expires in 1 hour */
});

page.open('http://casperjs.org', function (status) {

  console.log(page.cookies[0].name);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

I executed it using PHP

```
<?php

$output = shell_exec('phantomjs cookie-js --cookies-file=~/phantomjs/cookies.txt');


echo $output           //outputs ps_idssss

?>
```

IT successfully output the cookie but when I visits the http://casperjs.org, it never saved any cookie. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work because of the wrong order of arguments. Script name should be the last argument.

```
$output = shell_exec('phantomjs --cookies-file=~/phantomjs/cookies.txt cookie-js');
```

Comment: Hello thanks! I followed your instruction above and the cookies.txt file now has already have the cookies content however when I visited the http://casperjs.org, it has still no cookie what I do..What do I do? Please help..

Comment: I tried your script in console and it worked right. Make sure the command is actually executed. What is in $output variable? Should be `ps_idssss`.

Comment: Did you tried visiting the casperjs.org and check for cookies if it was save?

Comment: What do you mean "tried visiting casperjs.org"? I ran your script which does that. The cookie was present.

Comment: I mean if you tried visiting casperjs.org through browser....and check the cookie if it was present....Really?

Comment: You set the cookie with one browser (PhantomJS) but want to have it in another (like Google Chrome), is that what you're saying? That's not possible of course.

Comment: Ah.. okay I understand now thanks ..But is there anyway we can set cookie for external domain? I am really frustrated about this...

Comment: We *can* set cookie for an external domain, the script from your question does just that! It does that in PhantomJS though. If you want the same behaviour for any other browser, you could write an extension, I guess. You could open another question about cookies and {browser-name}.